# iPad Discharged and not charging

Tags: ipad, battery, charging

My iPad was in good health when it was used last. That was about 8 month ago. Now it wont come on and on connecting it to the charger, the low battery sign comes on with the 3 red stripes. That's all even after a couple of hours.

Is there any hope for the battery to recover?

Comment: You didn't mention the age of the iPad, but it does sound like you need a new battery.

Answer (score 1):

The iPad is charging now. Just that it remained with the zero charge indicator for over 5 hours although it was connected to its own charger which was working.the first charge took in all over 18 hours. Now it is working as expected. I.e., the charge cycles are only few hours.